# Is it possible to show remain time or percentage on module lazy loading module?

Tags: angular

I want to show loading times or percentages when lazy loading modules. I want to show the time it took to load the module in real time.

I have tried the `RouteConfigLoadStart` and `RouteConfigLoadEnd` methods and they work fine. When loading, the module loader component displays and when done the component switches off, but I want to show how much time is remaining to load the module.

**Component.ts:**

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart || event instanceof ResolveStart) {
    this.moduleLoading = true;
  }
  if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd || event instanceof ResolveEnd) {
    this.moduleLoading = false;
  }
});
```

**component.html:**

```html
<div class="content-wrapper" style="padding: 0px;">
  <div *ngIf="moduleLoading" class="square-box-loader" style="left: 56%;">
    <div class="square-box-loader-container">
      <div class="square-box-loader-corner-top"></div>
      <div class="square-box-loader-corner-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square-box-loader-square"></div>
  </div>
  <router-outlet *ngIf="!moduleLoading"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I want to show the remaining time to load the modules. For example, 5 seconds remaining or 10% loaded / 50% loaded, etc.

How would I go about showing percentages loaded or amount of time until loading is complete?

Comment: Does it take more than 1 second to load a module? How big is it? Isn't it cached once loaded, anyway?

Comment: Don't know the time some module import more than 15 module to load and some module only use three module so both have different time to load but the thing need is to what time take to load module?